# Identifying a story with a portal that only organic tissue can pass through

Tags: story-identification, books, teleportation

I'm looking for a book that I read when I was young (~1985). My guess is that it was published in the 70s or 80s.

In this story, a scientist (or more) created some sort of portal. Only organic tissue could pass through it. Metal (for example dental filling) just dropped on the floor. I remembered a passage where someone was exclaiming that it would be perfect to do medical examination.

After some tests with animals that could go inside and back safely from the portal, someone stuck its head inside, only to find blackness - some sort of cave. They could not touch the bottom, or anything.

They tried to do a human chain to reach the bottom without success (and in fact some people were lost).

A team decided to jump and see what was on the other side. I could not remember what happened next, except that they survived and build a society.

I really tried to identify the book without success. And I would love to re-read it was it is one of these book that I think about regularly.

Comment: Inorganic material just dropped out? Without harming the individual?

Comment: I recall a book with portals that didn't pass fillings as well, but can't recall much more about it. As I think I read it in middle school and the library there was pretty old I'm guess mine may be from earlier than 1970s. There were a pretty large number of Andre Norton juveniles in that library.

Comment: I read that one! I think I may even own the book still. I'm trying to get you the name.

Comment: I found the book in which it was, an old anthology, trying to get to the story name.

Comment: Nothing seems to match in that book, although I felt sure: http://science-fiction.pagesperso-orange.fr/jailu/jailu880.htm. You can read the stories by looking them up there: http://www.unz.org/Pub/FantasticAdventures-1951?View=Search

Comment: Considering my other readings, it might very well be from Robert Silverberg, as I read all I could find from him at a time.

Comment: This is soooo frustrating. I remember some more bits than the OP: after the discovery of the portal, the authorities stage a big TV-transmitted expedition using a team of firemen linked by a big rope to look inside. This ends very badly when one of them slips and the whole company falls inside.

Comment: searching for book and fireman together turns up Fahrenheit 451 >.<

Comment: @jv42 It's the same book! I wasn't sure it was firemen when I wrote my question, but you confirmed it.

Comment: Thinking about it further, they weren't using rope, but were instead half naked and linked arms to legs, so their chain breaks when a single fireman breaks.

Comment: After that public drama, the scientists are left to quietly experiment with the portal.

Comment: I'm not certain it's a small story. I remember that the book ended with a bunch of people jumping inside the portal and thinkg that "it's one of these book" where the ending is opened ended. Then discovering with delight later that there was a "Part 2" book, where they build the society".

Comment: @Xantec I have not determined the correct answer yet. Apparently, jv42 has read this book (his memory of the story concord with mine), but so far the title is still missing. :)

Comment: @Thierry-DimitriRoy My mistake, I thought you were saying jv42's links was it it. Nevermind.

Comment: Still searching, maybe one of these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Medicine_for_Melancholy (I read this anthology).

Comment: @jv42 I have that book, ill check it now!

Comment: @HansWassink Thanks a lot! I've read this in French, so most of the English titles don't remind me of much.

Comment: @jv42 Bwagh, I checked the entire book, AND The October Country by Bradbury and there is no mention of that story anywhere... I really want to read it now :) Ow, now I see I have the US version, maybe the UK version has that story...

Comment: Still no one found the title?! :(

Comment: @jv42 - They wouldn't have been able to use an actual rope, as that wouldn't count as "organic material".  Unless perhaps it was made out of hemp, and even then only if the portal happens to count dead/processed organic matter as valid organic material.  Does it?

Comment: @aroth I'm not certain the portal restriction was actually organic material, maybe it was metal in fact. Anyway, that maybe the explanation for the rope, also I don't recall how they get animals out after getting them in.

Comment: I'm not certain about the rope either. I remembered something as a human chain and thinking "this wouldn't work" - and it didn't :). As for the animal getting in and out, I don't remember how they did it.

Comment: Sounds like it has elements of the movie "The Fly" and the book "Dune".

Comment: How about *Tiger by the Tail and Other Science Fiction Stories* by *Alan E. Nourse*? It has one story that's vaguely like your description, *Tiger by the Tail*.

Comment: @Thierry-DimitriRoy thanks for notifying me, I'll go check this one!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you may be referring to a book by **Jerry Sohl** called

> Costigan’s Needle

The original copyright is 1953. My particular copy has a publication date of August 1968.

There's a Kindle edition on Amazon for $8.99 and they also have some used paperbacks starting at about $16.

Comment: Thanks!!! I'm 99% certain that this is the correct book! :)

Comment: Just a further note that there seems to be cheaper copies of the book on Amazon then I originally thought (just search the title for details).

Answer (score 1):

It was a Stephen King short story called "The Jaunt." It was published in a collection called *Skeleton Crew* in 1985. I still have it.

Comment: I have read the description from Wikipedia nad it does not seem to be what I'm looking for. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: I thought of "The Jaunt" as well, but they were using it for teleportation purposes, and couldn't be away to pass through. And it was a convict that made the first human trip, and died afterwards after seeing 'eternity'.